# How to make swing components interact with Libgdx

Tags: java, swing, libgdx

Lets say we have 2 java windows, 1 with the libgdx game and another with some swing components that interact with the game. And lets say I want to see screen coordinates in the game log, whenever clicking on the screen and only when a JCeckBox is selected on another window which is JFrame. I have the code to get the coordinates from the screen but how would I go about to make them appear only when that JCheckbox is selected?

Comment: Are you asking how to make information in one window available to the other ?  ( coordinates information available to the `JFrame` class or alternatively the `JCheckBox` state available to the `Libgdx` )

Comment: I figured out how to, yust make sure you use EventQueue.invokelater() also in libgdx then libgdx game engine will interact with swing components.